# Swift ios8: How to make single row picker with option for manual text entry?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to give my iPhone App user the option of whether to use a picker (i.e., scroll wheel) or keyboard to input the value of a field. I'd like it to where the current value of the field effectively displays as isolated text (i.e., as a label, with the picker and keyboard hidden). But the user can change the field's value by either (A) performing a single tap on the label to reveal the keyboard so the user can type in a different value; or (B) perform a swipe on the label to reveal the picker so the user can user the picker to change the value. This will present a very clean interface in my opinion, without the clutter of the keyboard, text field, or picker unless the user changes the value. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This control doesn't exist, but a possible solution would be to add a cell under the `UIPickerView` (assuming your using a table form) when the "Custom" option is selected and add a text field to that cell allowing custom input. Make sure you hide the cell if the `UIPickerView` value changes from "Custom" to avoid user confusion.